# How to remove mass trailing slashes(Nginx)

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, rewrite, regular-expressions

I need to remove mass trailing slashes, now I have

```
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

So `www.example.com/` becomes `www.example.com`.

It's good, but when I go to `www.example.com///` (any amount of slashes) it's not redirecting. I need to make any amount of slashes at the end redirect to a page without a slash.

Comment: try this: `\/+$`

Comment: "So `www.example.com/` becomes `www.example.com`" - it's not your rule that is doing that; it's the browser! Most browsers simply "hide" the solitary slash after the domain name (at the start of the URL-path) - it is still present in the request. (You should be able to see in the network traffic, that there is no redirect here.) See also this question on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser

Answer (score 2):

Nginx normalizes the URI by removing consecutive occurrences of `/` before processing it with the `rewrite` and `location` directives. So your rule never sees the consecutive `/`s. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

The original request is available as `$request_uri` and can be checked using an `if` block.

For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*/)/($|\?.*)) { return 301 $1$2; }
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.